# Convert one level mixed header dataframe to vertical dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The following dataframe have multiple column names with format `item:district`:

```
   date  price:dc  price:xc  price:cy  ratio:dc  ratio:xc  ratio:cy
0  2017        12        11        14       0.1       0.1       0.3
1  2018        14        12        15       0.2       0.7       0.6
2  2019        13        13        16       0.5      -0.2       0.8
```

Is it possible to convert it to a new dataframe as follows? Thanks.

```
   date district  price  ratio
0  2017       dc     12    0.1
1  2018       dc     14    0.2
2  2019       dc     13    0.5
3  2017       xc     11    0.1
4  2018       xc     12    0.7
5  2019       xc     13   -0.2
6  2017       cy     14    0.3
7  2018       cy     15    0.6
8  2019       cy     16    0.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` with columns with `:` by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with created index by non `:` columns before by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index('date')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(':', expand=True)
df = df.stack().rename_axis(('date','district')).reset_index()
print (df)
   date district  price  ratio
0  2017       cy     14    0.3
1  2017       dc     12    0.1
2  2017       xc     11    0.1
3  2018       cy     15    0.6
4  2018       dc     14    0.2
5  2018       xc     12    0.7
6  2019       cy     16    0.8
7  2019       dc     13    0.5
8  2019       xc     13   -0.2
```

If ordering is important one solution is create ordered categoricals:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(':', expand=True)

lvl = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns.levels[1], 
                          ordered=True, 
                          categories=df.columns.get_level_values(1).drop_duplicates())
df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(lvl, level=1)

df = df.stack().sort_index(level=[1,0]).rename_axis(('date','district')).reset_index()
print (df)
   date district  price  ratio
0  2017       dc     12    0.1
1  2018       dc     14    0.2
2  2019       dc     13    0.5
3  2017       xc     11    0.1
4  2018       xc     12    0.7
5  2019       xc     13   -0.2
6  2017       cy     14    0.3
7  2018       cy     15    0.6
8  2019       cy     16    0.8
```

Comment: Many thanks. If headers is split by multiple `:`s such as `a:price:xc:b`, `a:price:cy:b:c`, `a:price:xc:b:c:d`, I need to get the values after first and second `:`, at this case `price:xc`, `price:cy`, `price:dc` as `df.columns`, etc, how can I do that?

Comment: @ahbon - There is always same value `a` before first `:` for `price` column?

Comment: yes, I print `df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(lvl, level=1)`, they are not sharing same length.

Comment: @ahbon - Can you test `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'a:price', 'price').str.split(':', n=2, expand=True).droplevel(-1)` ?

Comment: I use `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("a:", "")`, then apply `df.columns = df.columns.str.split(':', n=2, expand=True).droplevel(-1)`, works perfectly. Great thanks. :) You're genius.

Comment: But I dont understand `droplevel(-1)`, why it can drop `:b:c:d` from `a:price:xc:b:c:d`?

Comment: @ahbon - Because it create also 3rd level by `:b:c:d` values, so `droplevel(-1)` remove it